# Compute $\lim_{x\to0} \ln^x(x)$

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{x\to0} \ln^x(x)$$

I know I can use L'Hospital and get an answer equal to one.

But how can he ask a question like this even if the function is not continuous from $[0, 1]$. It has only discrete solutions not a graph

Comment: Why does this function have only discrete values?

Comment: Is the function even defined near $0$?

Comment: Do you mean $(\log x)^x$ ... Do you restrict to $x>0$ so that $\log x$ is a real number?  Even so, for $x$ near zero, $(\log x)^x$ may have the form of negative number to an irrational power, and it is still not real.  By "discrete values" do you mean to allow $x$ only of the form even/odd integers?

Comment: By discrete, it seems that the OP recognizes not all $x\in(0,1)$ are defined on the reals for $(\log x)^x$. OP may be interested in a progression similar to the sequence $\log(1/(2n+1))^{1/(2n+1)}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given function doesn't have discrete values if you plot it on its natural domain.

Speaking about the natural domain of the function, since you're using a real exponent, which is typically defined as $a^x=e^{a\ln x}$, the natural domain of your function is $[1,+\infty)$. Hence you can't talk about a limit around $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x)=\ln^x(x)$ is defined when both the following conditions are fulfilled

- for existence of $\ln x$ we need $x>0$
- for existence of $a^x$ we need $\ln x>0 \implies x>1$

therefore the given function is defined for $x>1$ and therefore the limit for $x\to 0$ is meaningless.